# adding AWS public certificate with NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate, nginx-config

I am using EC2 and working with NGINX (by PuTTY); I chose *AWS Public Certificate* therefore I understood that to use *HTTPS* I need to configure the NGINX too.
I found some tutorial about it, but everywhere they add `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` that I haven’t seen in AWS certification.

How I can find AWS SSL certificates and `ssl_certificate_key`?
Or is there another solution for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can only use ACM SSL certificates with AWS Load Balancers, CloudFront and API Gateway. it is not possible obtain the certificate from ACM and install it directly on a server.

You can attach certificates issued with ACM to the AWS Load balancer and hide your instance behind the load balancer, more on this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb/)

If you want to manage ssl directly on your Nginx you will need to issue certificate with another tool i.e [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

[Using Free Let’s Encrypt SSL/TLS Certificates with NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/)

Comment: Amazon has removed letsencrypt support from more recent AWS Linux versions. In our case we'll have to look for another free solution and remake our entire configuration scripts

Comment: While this answer may be the high level overview of the problem, the link provided to AWS doesn't really establish a clear solution to the OP's question; as I have the same question, followed setting up a load balancer, but am unable to get `https` to work. I believe this has to do with a necessary change to `nginx` config, but no where in the link/solution is that clear.

Answer (score 3):

it is now possible by using:

> AWS Certificate Manager for Nitro Enclaves

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enclaves/latest/user/nitro-enclave-refapp.html

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/announcing-aws-certificate-manager-for-nitro-enclaves/

Comment: "Nitro Enclave" is an isolated execution environment in AWS. It is way far from the need to "import AWS ACM public certification to Nginx running inside EC2".

Comment: not sure what you meant, but nitro enclaves does exactly what OP asked - provides access to ACM certificate for use in nginx

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible with Nitro Enclaves, but is rarely a good solution for a single-instance NGINX host. At the moment, an ec2 nitro enclave demands a full 2 vcpus for itself. Unless the instance is large enough to trivially spare 2 vcpus, this method likely involves a bump in ec2 instance size, which eliminates any cost or simplicity advantage over using a load balancer.